# How to access Wicket Application from different thread?

Tags: java, jetty, wicket

I'm running Wicket 1.5 with Jetty and that works fine. But sometimes I have to restart jetty a few times and I have to login again when testing stuff. To avoid that I have a mocked ISessionListener which nicely gives me all the permissions I need. But I only want to use this in testcode for obvious reasons. My problem is that I want to set the ISessionListener after I start my test instance of Jetty. But I can't do this:

```
... //init Jetty
server.start();
Application.get();
```

Here I get the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: There is no application attached to current thread main
```

After server.start() almost only non-test code is touched. Only some mocked services where this can't be placed.

How can I access my Wicket Application from where I start Jetty without changing non-test code?

Thanks!

Comment: Have Jetty finished starting the application when you call `Application.get();`?

Comment: Yes, added a sleep before Application.get() to be sure. I can access the website before I get the exception.

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to access Wicket Application from a different thread.
In your background thread, access the Application like this:

```
String applicationKey = Application.getApplicationKeys().iterator().next();
Application application = Application.get(applicationKey);
```

Then, set the application instance you got in the Wicket ThreadContext.

```
ThreadContext.setApplication(application);
```

Finally, detach everything when you're done.

```
try {
   ....
} finally {
   ThreadContext.detach();
}
```

NOTE: Though the question was asked years back, I hope this helps some wandering googler:-)

Comment: I don't have any code like this anymore to test your solution, I'd have to dig very deep in "the archives". It look good though. Thanks for your help after al these years :)

Answer (score 0):

Add your listener from an IInitializer, i.e. add wicket.properties and your implementation to your test class folder.

Comment: This look like a good solution, could you elaborate a bit more? Maybe give an example? Thank for your help.